# Float 16 quantized Tflite model not working for custom models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a custom tensorflow model which I converted into tflite using the Float16 quantization as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#float16_quantization).
But the the input details of the tflite model using the tflite interpreter are

```
[{'name': 'input_1',
  'index': 0,
  'shape': array([  1, 256, 256,   3], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ -1, 256, 256,   3], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

while the output details are

```
[{'name': 'Identity',
  'index': 636,
  'shape': array([  7,   1, 256, 256,   1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([  7,  -1, 256, 256,   1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

Is something wrong with the conversion ?

I also received this warning while converting the tf model to tflite

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _defun_call, _defun_call, _defun_call, _defun_call, _defun_call while saving (showing 5 of 63). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _defun_call, _defun_call, _defun_call, _defun_call, _defun_call while saving (showing 5 of 63). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
```

**P.S** I also tried doing [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#dynamic_range_quantization) quantization, but received the same input/output details for that tflite model.

Answer (score 1):

Float16 and post-training quantization don not modify the input/output tensors but the intermediate weight tensors only. The above behavior looks like an intended behavior. If you want to fully quantize your model, try the full integer quantization. You can find the details at [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#full_integer_quantization).

Comment: but this type of integer quantization is not supported by GPU delegate. I want my model to support GPU delegate

Comment: In such case, you can stick with float16 mode. However, the float16 mode will not change the input/output tensor types but it will use float16 weights during executions in GPU delegate.

Comment: and what about the warning during conversion, does it mean some layer are unsupported ?

Comment: I think you can ignore them.